# Null Pointer Exception and App Crashes

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Everything compiles perfection fine but the moment i run the emulator in eclipse- the app crashes. Here the Log Cat. Ive posted the main_activity.java as well! Let me know if you need any other source code :) Any help is appreciated :)

**LOG CAT**

```
09-14 05:56:56.363: D/dalvikvm(771): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
09-14 05:56:57.613: E/Trace(771): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-14 05:56:58.222: D/dalvikvm(771): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 85K, 8% free 2560K/2768K, paused 32ms, total 39ms
09-14 05:56:58.222: I/dalvikvm-heap(771): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.221MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-14 05:56:58.262: D/dalvikvm(771): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3179K/3392K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
09-14 05:56:58.312: D/AndroidRuntime(771): Shutting down VM
09-14 05:56:58.312: W/dalvikvm(771): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-14 05:56:58.322: D/dalvikvm(771): GC_CONCURRENT freed 16K, 6% free 3188K/3392K, paused 24ms+12ms, total 56ms
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.overworldinnovations.datatool/com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  ... 11 more
```

**this is the MainActivity.java**

```
package com.overworldinnovations.datatool;

import info.datatool.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Convert", "Data Ranges", "" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText editDecimal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDecimal);

    final EditText editBinary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBinary);

    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        public void onClick(View arg0) {



            int decimal = Integer.valueOf(editDecimal.getText().toString());

            editBinary.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(decimal));

        }

    });

    // Initialization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

***fragment_convert.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ff8400" >
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDecimal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                android:inputType="numberSigned"
                android:maxLength="9" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

<Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
                android:text="Convert" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Enter the decimal value to be converted :)"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editDecimal"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Decimal"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttonConvert"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
                android:text="Binary"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editBinary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editDecimal"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ummm.. How about sharing the code?

Comment: which would you like? the main activities?

Comment: how about this line? `at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)`

Comment: if 36 means the line number that's this line  buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   maybe it has something to do with it being protected?

Comment: unable to start to start component activity , for this make sure all your extra added classes by you are registered in manifest and nothing is returning null in those activities plus run in debugger mode , it will take you to the exact point which is causing trouble.

Comment: `buttonConvert` is `null`. You need to find out why.

Comment: buttonConvert shouldn't be null. It compiles just fine :/

Comment: @user3681591 You are getting a **runtime error**, so the fact that it compiles is irrelevant.

Comment: In fact, a program that compiles without errors cannot guarantee that none of the references are `null`. This can only be detected at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently are using fragments. You need to separate the fragment-related logic from the activity-related logic. In particular, none of the views will be available in the activity's `onCreate()` method. Instead, you need to move all of your `findViewById()` calls to the fragment's `onCreateView()` method. This means you must also move all of the logic that depends on these views there as well.

The only logic that should remain in your activity's `onCreate()` is the code dealing with the tabs in the action bar.

Comment: Ohhh! So instead of placing it in my MainActivity.java i need to place it in the ConvertFragment.java?

Comment: @user3681591 Exactly!

Comment: Wow that makes more perfect sense! I've been so used to having to using told Tab syntax and I've never used this new fragmented layout. Thanks man! I am still getting a small error when i copy and past it all but I'm hoping i can figure it out... with the @override it says it's a syntax error but if i remove it i get TONS of errors...

Comment: now it says "Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete block statements" any idea what this means?

Comment: @user3681591 Do some more reading about fragments. In particular, you need to override `onCreateView()` rather than `onCreate()`. Be sure to **always** use the `@Override` annotation whenever you intend to override a method. The compiler errors you get are a great help to track down errors that go unnoticed otherwise. These errors **don't** mean to remove the `@Override`. Rather, they indicate other problems. Most likely in this situation, you need to check the parameters that `onCreateView()` should take.

Comment: @user3681591 I suggest you start a new question with your updated code and the error you are getting now. Feel free to ping me here when you do and I'll take a look.

Comment: If i post my correct .xml would you mind taking a look at it for me? I appreciate all of your help

Comment: @user3681591 As I said, you should start a new question as this one has been answered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61194/discussion-between-user3681591-and-code-apprentice).

Answer (score 0):

The buttonConvert is null. Post your activity_main.xml
Are you sure that you have a button with an id "buttonConvert" in your activity_main.xml ?

Update:
Based on your comment you are trying to access a view from the activity which is clearly not there. You should gain a reference in your corresponding fragment instead of the activity

Comment: I don't have it in my activity_main.xml but instead i have it in the corresponding fragment_convert.xml- ill post the code now

Comment: So that is your problem. you are trying to access a view from the activity which is clearly not there. You should gain a reference in your corresponding fragment instead of the activity

Comment: I added my code- could you tell me exactly how to do that? i didn't think i had to place the button in my activity_main.xml because i want the button to be on the fragment_convert.xml.

Comment: See @Code-Apprentice response. It's already explained there how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly shows where the issue is.

```
09-14 05:56:58.332: E/AndroidRuntime(771):  at com.overworldinnovations.datatool.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
```

that is `buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`

you have set the layout '**activity_main**' there (onCreate method) as the layout. and you get button as:

```
Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
```

But you have mentioned `buttonConvert` in `fragment_convert.xml` file, not in activity_main.xml file.